# Was ist "Umgangssprache"?

Tags: colloquial, standard-german

Immer wieder verwende ich beim Schreiben Ausdrücke aus der *Umgangssprache*. Auch hier bei uns wurden *"Umgangssprache"* und *"umgangssprachlich"* schon mehrfach genannt. Eine klare Definition dessen, was Umgangssprache und was Standardsprache sind, fehlt mir aber.

Bei vielen Wörtern und Ausdrücken mag es vielleicht unstrittig sein, dass sie nicht in die hochdeutsche Standardsprache gehören. Manchmal ist das aber nicht so klar. Hier ein Beispiel:

> **langen** *Verb*
>   **Gebrauch:** umgangssprachlich ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/langen), [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=langen&view=1))

Das mag für Sätze wie

> *"Mir langen meine Vorräte noch bis Montag. Der Zopf langt bis an den Boden. Er hat ihm eine gelangt"*

auch zutreffen. Was ist aber in einer Konstruktion wie dieser:

> *Der Schiffbrüchige langte nach einer vor ihm treibenden Planke.*

Wer definiert, was Standardsprache und was Umgangssprache ist? Wo liegen die Grenzen? Gibt es Gründe für eine solche Trennung? Sollte man und - falls ja - wann sollte man Umgangssprache meiden?

Comment: Ich lang dir gleich eine, solche Fragen zu stellen. ;)

Comment: Mir langt auch eine schöne Antwort.

Comment: Ist ziemlich Sueddeutsch. Also Umgangssprache in einem bestimmten Dialektraum.

Comment: @Jules: guter Einwand. Das Beispiel *langen* war allerdings nur, um zu zeigen, dass es evtl. auch eine Verwendung außerhalb der (von mir so gefühlten) Umgangssprache gibt, auch wenn sie so von Duden nicht vorgesehen ist. Siehe auch meine weiteren Beispiele im Kommentar zur Antwort unten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laut dem Tutorium "[Einführung in die Sprachwissenschaft](http://www.linglit.tu-darmstadt.de/fileadmin/linglit/janich/docs/Tutorium/Tutorium_Ling11.pdf)" von Patrick Bal (TU Darmstadt) gelten (unter anderen) folgende Merkmale:

Standardsprache:

> - überregional
> - stark normiert (Aussprache, Rechtschreibung, Grammatik)
> - in der Schule vermittelt (stellt i. d. R. nicht die primäre Sprachform im Spracherwerb dar)
> - "flexible Stabilität" (widerstandsfähig gegenüber Veränderungen, trotzdem anpassbar an neue Situationen)

Umgangssprache:

> - unscharf definiert und daher umstrittener Begriff in der Sprachwissenschaft
> - Begriff bezieht sich auf den heterogenen Bereich von Sprachvarietäten zwischen überregionaler Standardsprache und kleinräumig gebundenen Dialekten
> - Umgangssprache ist in diesem Sinne eine "Ausgleichsvarietät" zwischen Standardsprache und den Dialekten; sie beinhaltet in unterschiedlicher Gewichtung Elemente der Standardsprache und des Dialekts

Daraus schlussfolgere ich, dass die Standardsprache zu einem großen Teil normiert ist (siehe Rechtschreibreform) und sich in ihr die überregionalen Verwendungen niederschlagen.

Umgangssprache jedoch enthält weit verbreitete (aber nicht überregionale) Abweichungen von der Standardsprache. Wenn man also vom Standard abweicht und "ich lang Dir eine" sagt, dann ist das Umgangssprache, sonst würde ich Dir eine runterhauen.

Also: Immer wenn im Duden "umgangssprachlich" steht, bedeutet das "regionale Abweichung der Standardsprache".

Comment: Was machen wir aber mit den überregional gültigen Wörtern, die ebenso wie die Standardwörter sogar den "offiziellen" Rechtschreibregeln des "Rates" unterworfen sind? **Beispiele:** *sündhaft teuer*, *etwas ausbaden*, *ein mulmiges Gefühl*, *ein Junge*, *dran* für daran, *herumkommen*, *Kumpel*, *sich verhaspeln* ... (endlose Liste). +1 nur für **umstrittener Begriff** ;)

Comment: @Takkat: Wenn Du mein "überregional" unbedingt auf die Goldwaage legen willst, dann nimm die Formulierung mit der "Ausgleichsvarietät" ;) Ich empfehle auch dem Link zu folgen und die anderen aufgeführten Punkte zu beachten. Ich habe mir einige Kürzungen erlaubt. (Wenn die kein Copy/paste erlauben, dürfen sie sich nicht wundern, dass sie nicht richtig zitiert werden)

Comment: Das Konzept der "Ausgleichsvarietät" und Folgendes bestärkt mich darin, dass die Unterteilung völlig **willkürlich** vorgenommen wird.

Comment: Wie kommst Du denn darauf, @Takkat :)

Comment: Schöne Antwort; vielleicht könnte man ein bisschen davon in das Tag Wiki von "colloquial" packen, das sieht etwas dürftig aus...

Answer (score 3):

Man versteht den Begriff der Umgangssprache vielleicht besser, wenn man ihn vom kommunikationstheoretischen Standpunkt aus betrachtet. Ein Merkmal der Umgangssprache ist ihre Ökonomie: Gegenüber hochsprachlichen Formen ist sie durch zahlreiche Auslassungen und Verkürzungen charakterisiert, durch Abkürzungen und Vereinfachungen. Die Umgangssprache ist knapper, hat aber weniger expliziten Informationsgehalt und einen meist viel kleineren Empfängerkreis als die Standardsprache. Was sie an Komplexität aufgibt, muss sie durch Kontext – d. h. Konsens und Vorwissen – wettmachen.

Wenn eine Frau zu ihrem Mann sagt:

> Geh nach oben, dreh die Wäsche um und mach Platz für eine neue Maschine.

dann muss der Mann Folgendes schon wissen, um diese Aufforderung zu verstehen:

1. Ich soll nach oben auf den Dachboden gehen
2. Auf dem Dachboden hängt die Wäsche
3. Die Wäsche hängt teilweise zusammengefaltet auf einem Wäscheständer
4. Man muss die Wäsche auseinanderfalten und neu falten, indem man die bisher nach innen gekehrten Flächen nach außen kehrt, damit sie auch trocknen können
5. Die Wäsche muss enger gehängt werden, damit für zusätzliche Wäsche Platz ist, die gerade neu gewaschen wird
6. Ich soll, wenn die neue Wäsche fertig gewaschen ist, diese nach oben tragen und aufhängen (unausgesprochen)

14 Wörter gegen 77 – eine gewaltige Ersparnis, natürlich nur für diesen speziellen Vorgang, denn irgendwann musste festgelegt werden, was mit den 14 Wörtern gemeint ist. Der Informationsverlust, der mit der Vereinfachung der Umgangssprache verbunden ist, lässt ihr auch relativ wenig Spielraum, wenn etwas völlig Neues vermittelt werden soll, eben weil sie auf Konsens und Vorwissen der am Gespräch Beteiligten aufbaut. Ihr Verständnis ist daher auch auf einen bestimmten Kreis von Kommunizierenden beschränkt, die das erforderliche Vorwissen haben, »mitdenken« und daher auch grobe, sinnstörende Ungenauigkeiten akzeptieren können.

Das kann, wie im Beispiel, ein sehr kleiner Kreis von Menschen sein oder eine größere Gruppe, die z. B. einen bestimmten Beruf, eine Lebensart oder besondere Interessen teilen. Auch die gemeinsame Benutzung eines bestimmten Mediums – z. B. Onlineforum oder Chat – kann zu einer eigenen Umgangssprache führen. Im letzteren Fall scheinen die Abkürzungen eine besondere Rolle zu spielen. Ich weiß z. B. bis jetzt nicht, was die Abkürzung *OP* bedeutet, die hier in Beiträgen immer wieder verwendet wird. Es gibt auch umgangssprachliche Wendungen, die von allen verstanden, aber nur in einem bestimmten durch Konsens gesicherten gesellschaftlichen Kontext verwendet werden.

Es leuchtet ein, dass die Leser einer Bedienungsanleitung für ein elektrisches Gerät mit (für sie) kryptischen Anweisungen wie im Beispiel oben wenig Freude hätten. Je weniger Gemeinsamkeiten die miteinander Kommunizierenden haben, je weniger sie auch über einander wissen, desto klarer genormt muss die Sprache sein. Es muss letztlich möglich sein, nur mit einer klaren Grammatik, Syntax und Semantik auch etwas mitzuteilen, wofür kein Vorwissen vorausgesetzt werden kann. Das kann und will die Umgangssprache nicht leisten, es ist die Aufgabe der Standardsprache. Diese lässt allerdings immer noch genug Raum für Interpretationen, weil sie weder eine Plansprache ist, die Bedeutungen und Ausdrücke und ihre Anwendungsmuster eineindeutig festlegt (wie z. B. Programmiersprachen), noch eine durchdefinierte Spezialsprache, wie wir sie in Gesetzestexten und anderen juristischen Texten finden.

Comment: *OP* heißt übrigens *original poster* und bezeichnet in Foren u. Ä. denjenigen, der einen Diskussionsstrang o. Ä. eröffnet hat. Auf Stack Exchange ist dies der Fragesteller. Nebenbei: Gibt es irgendeinen Grund, warum Du im Deutschen Geviertstriche statt Halbgeviertstriche für den Gedankenstrich nutzt? Beide dürften doch gleichermaßen schwer einzugeben sein.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke für die Erklärung von "OP". Ich verwende Geviertstriche, weil sie die echten Gedankenstriche sind, die anderen sind Bindestriche, die der einfacheren Eingabe wegen von den meisten auch als Gedankenstriche genutzt werden. Auf meinem Mac sind die "echten" Gedankenstriche mit Shift-Alt-Bindestrich leicht herzustellen. Übrigens werden auch die Kommentare hier automatisch mit diesem Zeichen abgeschlossen, zum Vergleich: -

Comment: Du verwechselst Halbgeviertstriche mit Viertelgeviertstrichen. Letztere werden im Deutschen als Binde-, Trenn- und Ergänzungsstrich genutzt. Halbgeviertstriche werden im Deutschen als Gedanken-, Bis- und Streckenstrich genutzt. Geviertstriche werden im Deutschen praktisch gar nicht mehr genutzt, aber werden im Englischen je nach Styleguide als Gedankenstriche genutzt. [Hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbgeviertstrich#Eingabe_bei_Computersystemen_und_-programmen) solltest Du finden, wie Du die wirklichen »echten« Gedankenstriche nutzt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich kann, ehrlich gesagt, kein Problem darin erkennen, dass ich für Gedankenstriche die längere Version statt der Halbgeviertstriche verwende, es hat für mich auch keinen besonderen Grund als den, sie deutlich von den Bindestrichen abzusetzen.

Comment: Was Du verwendest sind keine »längere Version der Halbgeviertstriche«, sondern Geviertstriche. Damit verstößt Du gegen die üblichen typografischen Koventionen im Deutschen und liegst damit, wenn man so möchte, nicht minder falsch als jemand, der Viertelgeviertstriche (Bindestriche) für Gedankenstriche verwendet. (Natürlich ist das alles ein Luxusproblem. Aber es verwundert mich halt, dass jemand einen besonderen Aufwand betreibt, um ein Sonderzeichen zu nutzen, aber dann das falsche nutzt. Das ist in etwa so wie Amerikaner die den Mathematiker Erdős *Erdös* schreiben.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  Das ist tatsächlich ein Luxusproblem für Typographen, vor allem, weil es mir um die optische Abgrenzung zum Bindestrich geht. Wie ich dem Wikipedia-Artikel entnehme, sind Geviertstriche nicht "falsch", sondern veraltet. So what? Den erhöhten Aufwand mit der Tastatur muss ich so oder so in Kauf nehmen.

Comment: Naja , derartige Konventionen erleichtern wie Rechtschreibung das Erfassen von Texten . Wenn dort ein Gedankenstrich plötzlich ungewöhnlich lang ist, kann dies den Lesefluss brechen – genauso wie ein Tippfehler oder vergleichbare typografische Fehler , die ich absichtlich in diesen Kommentar eingebaut habe .

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Wenn es nur Tippfehler sind, sollte man sie vermeiden. Wenn man eine Absicht damit verbindet, kann man auch mit dem Schriftbild viel bewirken. Immerhin ist das die einzige Möglichkeit, sich schreibend nonverbal auszudrücken.

Comment: Schöner Hinweis auf fachspezifische Umgangssprache. Wenn ich im Labor von *säulen, quenchen* oder *(ab-) rotieren* spreche, wissen alle meine Kollegen was gemeint ist. Schreiben sollte man das in seiner Arbeit aber nicht (nur die englische Übersetzung von *quenchen* – *to quench* – gilt auf English als wissenschaftliche Standardsprache.

Answer (score 0):

Was die Definition angeht, gibt es zumindest beim üblichen Verdächtigen etwas zur [Umgangssprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umgangssprache) im Gegensatz zur [Standardsprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardsprache).

Was die Grenzen angeht, so sind sie zumindest bei der Umgangssprache nicht festgelegt, sondern richten sich, wie der Begriff schon sagt, nach dem alltäglichen *Umgang* damit.

Gründe für eine Unterscheidung liegen dann einfach darin, dass es Sinn macht, eine einheitliche Regelung für Deutschland und ggf. den gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum zu haben, es aber immer regionale Sitten und Gebräuche geben wird.

Ein gutes Beispiel ist der Gebrauch des Präteritums. In einem Buch liest man

> Peter sagte mir, er habe Hunger.

Die meisten Deutschen würden das aber als „gestelzt“ ansehen beim sprachlichen Gebrauch und eher etwas sagen wie

> Peter hat mir gesagt, er hat Hunger.

Das Gleiche gilt aber auch für die in der Frage genannten unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen eines Wortes. Wenn *langen* schon laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/langen) mehrere Bedeutungen haben kann, so gibt es in der Umgangssprache noch deren mehr.

Bezüglich des letzten Punkts aus der Frage gelten wie immer bei Kommunikation der Kontext und die Personen, die daran beteiligt sind. Denselben Satz sage ich anders, wenn ich ihn in einer Rede ausspreche oder zu Hause sage und wenn ich ihn meinem Chef oder meinem Kumpel sage.

Als Fazit würde ich formulieren: Umgangssprache ist etwas, das sich aus dem alltäglichen Gebrauch bildet und vielen Einflüssen und Veränderungen unterworfen ist und man in der alltäglichen Kommunikation benötigt. Standardsprache ist der Versuch, aus den vielen Möglichkeiten eine Einheitlichkeit herzustellen, die man vor allem in der Schriftsprache und in offiziellen Kommunikationen benötigt.