# Wie nennt man eine "Pusteblume" in Standarddeutsch?

Tags: single-word-request, colloquial

Erst seit etwa dem 20. Jahrhundert gibt es den Begriff [**Pusteblume**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pusteblume), der aber nach Duden und anderen Lexika als [umgangssprachlich](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/was-ist-umgangssprache) oder sogar als *"[Kindersprache](http://de.pons.eu/deutsch-englisch/Pusteblume)"* bezeichnet wird.

Gibt es einen anderen Begriff für *"Pusteblume"* in der Standardsprache, und wenn nicht, wie sollte man dann eine Pusteblume bezeichnen, wenn man keine Umgangssprache benutzen will?

Hier ein Beispiel mit entsprechendem Kontext:

> "Löwenzahn sollte frühzeitig und gründlich entfernt werden, bevor sich die *Pusteblumen* ausbilden."

Comment: In Deinem Beispiel könnte man auch so etwas schreiben wie *"...bevor die Samen reif sind."*, und den Begriff *Pusteblume* so komplett vermeiden.

Comment: "Löwenzahn sollte frühzeitig und gründlich entfernt werden, bevor sich der Schirmfliegerpflanzenkopf ausbildet." - Deutsch ist so eine wunderbare Sprache :D

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Sagt ein deutscher!

Comment: @Gigili, natürlich, sonst sagt es ja keiner ;)

Comment: Die Frage sollten lauten: auf Standarddeutsch.

Comment: @Ella: Nach [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsch) geht beides. Das wäre aber doch eine tolle Frage für hier, oder?

Comment: Aus Spiegel-Online: ["Es besteht zu 99,99 Prozent aus Luft, so dass es auf einer Pusteblume liegen kann, ohne sie zu zerstören."](http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/technik/aerographit-leichtestes-material-der-welt-entwickelt-a-843819.html)

Comment: Ist mit Standarddeutsch Hochdeutsch gemeint? Der Begriff stört mich.

Comment: Nicht nur in Österreich, in ganz Süddeutschland sagt kein Mensch ,,pusten''. Bei der Schweiz bin ich mir nicht sicher, wie dort der gängige Begriff für ,,Luftballons aufblasen'' ist.

Comment: @PhilippE.: Ich verstehe den Zusammenhang nicht ganz. Richtig, als einzelnes Wort ist "pusten" auch hier in Südwestdeutschlamd relativ ungebräuchlich, aber der feststehende Ausdruck "Pusteblume" scheint dennoch verbreitet zu sein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die beste Wahl ist schlichtweg *Löwenzahn*, denn die *Pusteblume* ist nichts anderes als "[gewöhnlicher Löwenzahn](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gew%C3%B6hnlicher_L%C3%B6wenzahn)".

*Pusteblume* ist deswegen umgangssprachlich, weil es kein "offizieller Name" dieser oder irgendeiner anderen Pflanze ist. Der *Löwenzahn* erhielt den Beinamen *Pusteblume* aufgrund dessen, dass Kinder nun mal gerne dem *Löwenzahn* durch Pusten - ähm - bei seiner Fortpflanzung helfen ;)

Dazu auch ein Ausschnit aus dem [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=pusten):

> Pusteblume f. verblühter Löwenzahn, dessen zurückgebliebene Fruchtstände von Kindern weggepustet werden (zuerst bezeugt im 19. Jh. in nd. Mundart, doch wohl älter).

[Alternativen](http://www.najuversum.de/index.php?action=page&pageid=9830) sind *Kuhblume*, *Milchbusch* oder *Butterblume*, wobei letzterer uneindeutig ist (Ich kenne etwas anderes als Butterblume) und die anderen sind - denke ich - ausschließlich regional bekannt; zumindest habe ich beide noch nie gehört.

Ich sehe kein Problem damit, den *Löwenzahn* als *Pusteblume* zu bezeichnen, wenn du auf den entsprechenden Endstadium (verwelkt, mit herangewachsenen Samen) hindeuten willst. Wenn du im Allgemeinen über die Pflanze sprichst, nimm *Löwenzahn*, das versteht jeder.

Comment: In der Umgangssprache, so wie ich sie kenne gibt es einen deutlichen Unterschied zwischen "Löwenzahn" und "Pusteblume": Mit "Pusteblume" kann man aus meiner Sicht nur die weißen Fruchtkörper (Botaniker, zu Hilfe!) des Löwenzahns bezeichnen. Sprich: Wenn ein Kind erzählt, es habe eine Menge Pusteblumen gepflückt, dann kann man das nicht so einfach übersetzen ohne dass der Sinn verändert wird, weil es eben keinen griffigen Standardsprache-Ausdruck für die weißen Flaumkugeln gibt.

Comment: @0x6d64 Hm... Unter dem Begriff Pusteblume habe ich immer das Gesamte verstanden. Eigentlich habe ich mir nie darüber Gedanken gemacht; als Kind habe ich das sowieso nur begrenzt verstanden und seit dem ich es vollends verstehe, interessieren mich Pusteblumen nicht mehr. ... Das mit dem Übersetzen versteh ich jetzt aber nicht. Ins Englische? Common Dandelion / (Dandelion) clock / Blowball

Comment: Oh, vor dem "übersetzen" sollte noch ein "in Standardsprache" rein. Meine Ansicht ist ungefähr so: Man kann Pusteblume und Löwenzahn nicht gleichsetzen, weil das eine die weiße Kugel (mit Stengel) bezeichnet und das andere eine Pflanze, die ab und zu die weißen Kugeln trägt. Es gibt außer eine botanischen Fachbeschreibung von den weißen Kugeln keinen anderen Ausdruck für Pusteblumen, also kann der Ausdruck auch nicht "kindlich" sein, denn Erwachsene müssen zwangsläufig den selben Begriff verwenden wenn sie nicht den botanischen Fachbegriff nutzen.

Comment: Andererseits reden Erwachsene auch eher mit Kindern über Pusteblumen, oder sie unterhalten sich untereinander über ihre Kindertage. So gesehen kommt dann immer "Kindersprache" mit ins Spiel, der Begriff ist dann durchaus kindlich. Insgesamt freue ich mich grade wie ein Kind über diese interessante Frage :3

Comment: Pusteblume = weiß, Hundeblume = gelb, Löwenzahn = Salat/Sendung.

Comment: "Die beste Wahl ist schlichtweg *Löwenzahn*" - ich verstehe nicht, wie du zu dieser Einschätzumg gelangst. Ein gelber Löwenzahn ist eben gerade *keine* Pusteblume. Das bestätigt ja auch das Zitat in deiner eigenen Antwort genau so.

Answer (score 4):

"Pusteblume" ist nicht im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum in Verwendung, weil auch das Wort "pusten" nicht überall geläufig ist.

In Österreich (zumindest in Ostösterreich) wird "pusten" eigentlich nur von Touristen und Immigranten aus Deutschland benutzt. Stattdessen sagt man hier: "blasen".

Man *bläst* eine Kerze aus. Wenn ein Kind seine Finger verbrannt hat, *bläst* man über die Verletzung um sie zu kühlen, und wenn man Staub von einer alten Vase entfernen will, kann man versuchen ihn wegzu-*blasen*. Man *bläst* auch einen Ballon auf und man *bläst* einen Marienkäfer vom Finger.

Daher *pustet* hier auch niemand auf irgendwelche Blumen, sondern Kinder *blasen* die Samen von der reifen Blume. Deswegen heißt die Pflanze aber trotzdem nicht "Blaseblume" oder so ähnlich, sondern schlichtweg "Löwenzahn".

Comment: Ich glaube in Deutschland traut sich keine Mutter ihren Jungen zu fragen: "Soll ich mal blasen?" ;)

Comment: @JohnSmithers So true. Ich weiß nicht, wie viel Ironie du in denen Kommentar gesteckt hast, aber das Wort *blasen* wird in der Tat weitesgehend vermieden, wann immer man eine Doppeldeutigkeit vermeiden will. Und bei Kindern (nicht nur bei Jungen) versucht man dann auch das Wort *pusten* eher zu vermitteln, als *blasen*. - Wobei, die armen Kinder, die können sich doch eh nichts darunter vorstellen.

Comment: Wobei ich mich gerade frage, woher die vulgäre Bedeutung von *blasen* kommt... Man benutzt zwar den Mund ja, aber *blasen* bedeutet eigentlich soviel wie "kräftig Luft ausstoßen, heftig wehen" Und selbst bei einer Herleitung von Blasinstrumenten will mir das nicht in den Sinn kommen... Hach, ich glaub ich hab ne etymologische Frage :)

Comment: @Em1: Ingogermanisch "bhel" heißt "anschwellen lassen". Gotisch wurde es dann zu "blesan" bzw. "ufblesan". Auch "bläjen" ist belegt. Dann entwickelten sich daraus zwei ähnliche Wörter, nämlich "blähen" bzw. "aufblähen" und "blasen" bzw. "aufblasen". Der Ausdruck "blasen" für Fellatio ist recht alt, und das Wort "blasen" hat erst später den Bedeutungswandel von "aufblähen" zu "pusten" gemacht. "Pusten" ist übrigens niederdeutschen Ursprungs und stammt vermutlich aus den Niederlanden (poesten) oder dem Schwedischen (pusta).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nun, jetzt habe ich keine Frage mehr :( Danke für die *Aufklärung*. :)

Comment: Für mich gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *pusten* und *blasen*. Beim Pusten wird relativ kurz und kräftig Luft aus dem Mund befördert. Beim Blasen hingegen wird ein viel größeres Luftvolumen bewegt, sodass der Vorgang länger dauern kann und man gegebenenfalls mehrere Luftstöße braucht, um zum Beispiel eine *Blase* zu erzeugen. Beispiel: Wenn ich eine Kerze auspuste, dann mit einem kurzen, intensiven Luftstoß; wenn ich die Kerze ausblasen will, dann muss ich dazu tief luftholen, um einen längeren Luftstrom erzeugen zu können.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Wenn man eine Kerze mit einem kurzen, intensiven Luftstoß löscht, sagt man in Österreich: *ausblasen.* In Österreich pusten nur deutsche Immigranten und Touristen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, interessant.